# Can I use dd with a mounted partition?

Tags: linux, dd

I would like to backup my `/home` (nvme0n1p3) partition to a `backup.img` file using `dd`. Can I do that while the partition is mounted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically you can, there will be no error from `dd` (unless the device is faulty); but you don't want to because the resulting image may be inconsistent.

Sequentially imaging something that can change in the meantime may give you a result that will be an analogue of [panorama fail](https://www.google.com/search?q=panorama+fail&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X). Different parts of the result are taken at different moments. Even if the world (or your source filesystem) is consistent at any given moment, the result takes partial information from *different* moments and inconsistency appears.

Keeping the filesystem unmounted or mounted as read-only will prevent it from changing. You can remount `/home` as read-only with:

```
mount -o remount,ro /home
```

(this requires `sudo`). The command will fail (`mount point is busy`) if there is at least one file open for writing. For completeness: `-o remount,rw` remounts read/write.

Comment: This is about the only area that, IMHO, Linux might benefit from a Windows feature: Volume Shadow Copy. By taking a snapshot of the disk state, VSS allows a mounted, active Windows partition to be imaged (fairly) safely.